# WPF style for Border affecting window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple WPF (4.0) sample that aims the demonstrate the strangeness I am facing in another project. The sample tries to display a few rectangle shapes for which I use Border elements. Below is the markup:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window3" Height="1000" Width="1500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" x:Key="grad">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"  />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"  />
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource grad}" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border />
        <Border />
        <Border />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In the designer this looks exactly how I imagine it: 3 squares next to each other on the top left of the screen. However at runtime only 1 is displayed and the rest of the window is black. Seemingly the window's content itself is affected by the layout properties. If I use Rectangles instead of Borders the sample works just fine. Can anyone explain please why I am seeing this behaviour (inheritance related maybe)? Also is the difference between design-time view and run-time view basically a VS bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
 <Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="myborder">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource grad}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border Style = {StaticResources myborder}/>
    <Border Style = {StaticResources myborder}/>
    <Border Style = {StaticResources myborder}/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now its OK.

**EDIT:**
Each Winwow's template is a Border that has a AdornerDecorator in it. And in that decorator there is a `ContentPresenter`. So when you create a default style for borders it affect the Window's border too.

Comment: Thank, it works. However I am more curious about why I am experiencing this strange behaviour (only on Border, different design-time and run-time view)? Can you please explain the issue in detail?

Comment: @GyőriLászló Do you have blend?